# Oracle SQL to get first day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

Requirement is input date should produce first day of the month.
Condtions are:

1. If the date entered is between 16-nov to 30-nov, then the first day will be 16-nov.
2. if the date entered is between 1-nov to 15-nov , then the first day will be 01-nov.
3. for all other month it should return 01st day of corresponding month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Tim Biegeleisen's solution, simplifying it and avoid the date-to-text-to-date conversions. Note the use of `TRUNC` to get the first date of the period.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_COL) = 11 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_COL) >= 16
            THEN TRUNC(DATE_COL, 'MONTH') + 15
        ELSE TRUNC(DATE_COL, 'MONTH')
    END AS FIRST_OF_MONTH
FROM T1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a lengthy `CASE` expression to handle this, containing the logic for the three cases you mentioned in your question.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date) = 11 AND
                 EXTRACT(day FROM date) >= 16
            THEN TO_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM date) || '-11-16', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
            ELSE TO_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM date) || '-' || EXTRACT(month FROM date) ||
                                 '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
       END AS newDate
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Actually you can skip the 2nd `WHEN` condition, because "all other should return 1st of month" implies "when between 1-nov to 15-nov then 1st of Nov"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Nice observation, I have updated my query.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the super-fast response.. working as i needed.